# Protecting important config settings in posts from users without knowledge?

Tags: feature-request

I'm frequently seeing people who are new to programming post some important configuration keys along with their code without knowing that other people can utilize this key and do some other stuff.

Here's one such example which I saw right now that made me to post this :

[image]

There are some good people who edit the questions and replace the keys with `xxxxxx`. And there are some who say to edit the posts to remove those keys. My point is,

> People can still get those keys when they click on revisions, right?

Since many people visit Stack Overflow, it would be nice if there was something that alerted the moderators to remove/blur only that corresponding revision, or at least give permission to read only to that user who created the question.

The above might not be a good solution, but I feel this is such one problem that Stack Overflow moderators need to consider soon to implement a good solution.

Comment: How should the SO engine detect such edits in particular, to e.g. _alert moderators_?

Comment: Why not an user alerts if there's any custom flag or any feature that alerts the Mods?

Answer (score 16):

These kinds of accidental disclosures happen all the time on this site. The standard procedure for this starts with raising a custom flag for moderators that points this out.

We then can evaluate the severity of the disclosure. If it's something trivial like an email address, we might leave the revisions alone or simply delete the post.

If it's something that puts innocent people at risk, like keys, passwords, or personal information, these revisions can be burned from the database. However, this cannot be done by a moderator, so we need to inform an SE employee about this.

We don't have a great workflow for this, though, and SE employees are extremely busy, so this can take a while sometimes. In the meantime, we will often delete the post with the sensitive information.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Brad Larson. You can still see some posts holding keys in revision in some popular tags like `Twitter`, `Facebook, `Parse.com``. Until a good solution from SE employee, i feel it would be nice to simply delete the post and informing to that user through mail or something and asking them to re-post without keys :)

Answer (score 11):

I've seen it happen before too - although in my scenario it was someone posting credentials to a live database, which is pretty terrifying.

The real problem here isn't that the information is posted, but that the user *blindly copied* sensitive information from their code to a public website, which to many companies is a firing offense.  There's likely little recourse we can take on that information, because:

- Once it's posted publicly, you have to assume that a large number of people have already seen it.
- Moderators can't delete revisions to my recollection; only employees can do that.
- It's difficult to suss out what is sensitive information and what isn't without context from the OP, and by that time it's too late (refer to bullet 1)

It may be worth adding something to warn a user if a configuration-style file is detected, which says something like:

> Be sure that this file doesn't have any sensitive information, such as URLs, IP addresses, usernames, or passwords, before you post.

...although at that point I feel like we've stepped into a role we *really* shouldn't be in, which is NDA enforcement.

Comment: "It may be worth adding something to warn a user if a configuration-style file is detected" - Yes,  i go with you. Definitely i agree a user MUST know he shouldn't post. But, when an user who started to learn coding 've no knowledge about how important those keys are, even when i started i once posted with keys and deleted myself later once i searched in google. All i'm saying that it would be better to look after this which i feel this is one such big problem without any good solution.

Comment: No seriously, I really don't think this is an avenue we want to go down.  If the user doesn't know enough not to post sensitive, internal applications to a public website without *at the bare minimum* removing any sensitive information or passphrases, then I wouldn't trust them in my company, and most sensible leads/hiring managers would feel similarly.   We can't police all of the content because it *might* contain sensitive information.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that your staff posted a content on a site like SO for a problem? :) BTW in these generation, kids are started to learn coding in the earlier stages itself and definitely most of em would not 've much knowledge about keys when they begin. So, if they face any quest, they simply posts the entire code along with keys believing that it is necessary to get the solution.

Comment: One may never know, which is lucky for the employee, but that's in the best case.  The worst case could be that someone actually does compromise the system.  Also, since search engines index this content, it wouldn't be a surprise during an audit to do a search and see if any keys turn up online.  That said, I stick strongly to my original assessment:  a user that doesn't know enough not to post sensitive information on a public site should not be working with sensitive code.  Mistakes can and do happen, but my sentiment is towards the users that will blindly paste their problem code here.